# How do make soft-body balls go through a hole?

Tags: modeling, animation, collision, soft-body

I'm currently working on a tutorial for a soft-body obstacle course, and I want the balls to go down into a funnel. However, when they land on it, they get stick to it, when I want them to roll down into the smaller hole in the funnel, go through it, and land on the plane below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to solve this problem so I can keep working on making my own course, but that's something that's hard for me to get past.

Here's where I am in the tutorial I'm working on...

https://youtu.be/4gYsxqNJyu8?t=520

Here's my file...
[image]

Comment: By removing the Solidify modifiers, directly modeling a non-zero width (just extruded in Z-positive direction by 0.1) on the funnel, and recalculating normals (they were wrong after I made this modeling change, originally, I was able to get the balls to go through the funnel. I'm a little unsure if there's a nice way to get it to work with the Solidify modifiers on; maybe others know more.

Comment: I was also able to get the balls to go through the funnel by just increasing the width on your funnel's Solidify modifier from 0.01 to 0.4. I suspect that 0.01 is too small, especially given the Physics > Sensitivity > Margin for the funnel is set to 0.04, and that the Solidiify's Offset is -1 (but I have not succeeded in getting it to work just by decreasing the Sensitivity Margin or by altering the Solidify offset).

Comment: I tried doing that, but I'm more of a visual and hands-on learner, so I would like you to explain that better and use pictures to help explain the solution.

Comment: The second suggestion I made is probably simple enough that it doesn't require any pictures: just increase your Solidify modifier's thickness from 0.01 to 0.4, and that should work. I don't want to post this as a formal answer because I'm hoping someone will come along with a more principled explanation for what overall combination of settings should be expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

So when physics don't do what I want, I make new physics-only meshes.

[image]

Okay, so first thing I did here was to look at the collider funnel.  The solidify modifier on this was *so* thin that I'm pretty sure it was confusing the physics, and any softbody verts that made it through the funnel could never recover.  So I just got rid of the solidify modifier.

After that, your vertex normals were backwards of what you wanted: we want the balls to collide with the top of the funnel, and if they blink through, we want them to get pushed back to the top of the funnel.  So I recalculated normals inside on the funnel mesh.  This pic is shown with "face orientation" enabled in the overlays.

After that, I still wasn't perfectly happy with the collision-- so I made a new collider.  I recommend always thinking of your *physics* world as separate from your *rendering* world.  The wireframe mesh is a slight duplicate of the funnel, raised up a little, with a slight lip created so the colliders don't get hung up on the edge of the collider.  Then I can remove the collision on the original mesh, and set the new collider not to display in renders (and set it to a wireframe viewport display so I know it's just for physics.)

Few other things:  You don't need rigid body on anything; soft body doesn't pay attention to that, only to collision.  You should probably apply scale on your floor.

Comment: How do I make a new collider that fits what you described? How do I apply scale to the floor of my animation? How do I alter the mesh of the funnel to fit the new collider?

Comment: Does this look like an improvement? Is there anything else I need to improve for it? There's still a bit of clipping. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=LnPSm8eZ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LnPSm8eZ/)

Comment: I didn't look at the file.  If it's good enough for you, it's good enough; if it's not, it's not.  If there's clipping, then edit the collision mesh so that it prevents the clipping.  You make a new collider by duplicating your existing collider and then editing it.  You can apply scale with ctrl a.  You alter a mesh by moving the verts in edit mode....

Comment: How do you duplicate a collider and edit it?

Comment: It is a mesh.  Select it, then shift D to duplicate it.  To edit it, tab into edit mode and move verts around.